# Find derivative of function with $\sin$ and $\ln$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have to find derivative of next function:
$$y=3x^5-5x^4+7\sin2x-\ln(2x+3)$$
I assue that can apply power rule for $3x^5$ and $-5x^4$ which will produce $y=15x^4-20x^3$, but I do not know how to continue. Please explain step by step and describe what rules you must be used for solving this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Chain rule here to get the derivative. The chain rule says that $\frac{d(f o g)}{dx}=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. If $y=f(u)$ and $u=g(x)$ then we can abbreviate it as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}.\frac{du}{dx}$$

Refer to any standard Calculus book for reference.

Now by chain rule $(sin(2x))'=\frac{d(sin(2x))}{d(2x)}\times \frac{d(2x)}
{dx}=2cos(2x)$

And similarly $(ln(2x+3))'=\frac{d(ln(2x+3))}{d(2x+3)}\times \frac{d(2x+3)}
{dx}=\frac{2}{2x+3}$

Comment: Can you apply that to current task?

Comment: Yes, I just did. Learn the method and then try some questions yourself

Comment: I see $(sin(2x))$ but it has to be $7sin2x$

Comment: No No! You have to take the derivative of $sin(2x)$ with respect to $2x$. Assume $u=2x$ then take derivative of $sin(u)$ with respect to $u$ and then derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to solve my task.

Comment: You say you see $ (\sin(2x))$ above remember if there is a constant multiple such as the 7 you ask about, all you have to do is multiply your derivative of $(\sin(2x))$ by it.

Comment: Can I see task solved with explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that :

$$\frac{d(\sin (ax+b))}{dx}=a \cdot \cos (ax+b)$$

and also that

$$\frac{d \ln (ax+b)}{dx}=\frac{a}{ax+b}$$

Comment: Can you apply that to current task?

Comment: which refers to b in $7sin2x$

Comment: @TeodorKolev First, you need to know that the $7$ is just a constant, which is outside the function. You need not to worry for that. Just keep it as it is. For your question, compare $2x$ with $ax+b$ and think about what do you get the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Can I see task solved with explanation?

Comment: @TeodorKolev Are you a highschool student? If yes, then in which grade/standard? I am asking this because you need to have basic knowledge of derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you need to know that d(sin(x))/dx= cos(x) and that d(ln(x))/dx= 1/x.  I would be surprised if you were asked a question like this without already knowing those.  Then, with the "2x" and "2x+ 3" in those functions, use the "chain rule".